# Why use the discrete demand setting at all?

Tags: facility-location

Currently, I am working on facility location problems and I noticed why we use discrete demand setting at all. If the problem is to allocate customers to a facility and we have millions of customers, why do we do use still use discrete setting in this case?

I understand the lack of literature devoted to continuous problems (for its difficulty) but does discrete demand setting make sense at all?

Comment: What do you mean by "discrete demand"? is it that the values of the customer demands belong to $\mathbb{N}$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: yep, that is right

Comment: I don't have time to write a long answer, so I will just write a short comment. Real numbers do not exist in computers. Computers manipulate integers. Floating point numbers are a nice trick to try to mimic the behavior of real numbers, but they have very bad properties such as $a + b - a \neq b$. So if we can avoid using them, we do. In practice, fixed-point numbers are often enough and can easily be modeled with integers with a large enough multiplier